# OpenID authentication with Google failing randomly

Tags: scala, openid, playframework-2.0

When using `OpenId` lib (scala version) with **Google**, I randomly get an exception:

```
 application - Authentication.openIDCallback error on callback from open id
play.api.libs.openid.Errors$AUTH_ERROR$: null
    at play.api.libs.openid.Errors$AUTH_ERROR$.<clinit>(OpenIDError.scala) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0]
    at play.api.libs.openid.OpenID$$anonfun$verifiedId$6$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(OpenID.scala:84) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0]
    at play.api.libs.openid.OpenID$$anonfun$verifiedId$6$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(OpenID.scala:81) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.STMPromise$$anonfun$map$1$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(Promise.scala:185) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0]
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch$$anonfun$either$1.apply(Exception.scala:110) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch$$anonfun$either$1.apply(Exception.scala:110) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
```

The exception is raised in code that processes the answer to the `OpenID` request, default Play 2.0 code, not mine. It seems as if Google wasn't returning the proper answer, but only happens sometimes.

Anyone knows why this happens?

Comment: Sniff the HTTP response and post that. I think there might be random 500 errors from their service but would need to see it to be sure.

Comment: actually, i think your callback urls don't match. that's why google is barking on you

Comment: @StevenLuu as far as I udnerstand if the callback didn't work I wouldn't get any request, so no error...

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  For me it almost seems like every other time works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had exactly the same problem. I recommend using OpenID4Java.

Here is what we use https://gist.github.com/4083410